# Can I maintain two distinct JSON Serializer/Deserializer on a given class with Jackson?

Tags: jackson

I have a class that I want to serialize and deserialize to two different JSON formats. These formats are incompatible and need different serializers.

I've written `StdSerializer` and `StdDeserializer` implementations and registering them before using them:

```kotlin
fun example1() : String {
 val jsonMapper = JsonMapper()
 val simpleModule = SimpleModule()

 simpleModule.addSerializer(ItemTree::class.java, SerializerA())

 jsonMapper.registerModule(simpleModule)
 return jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(this)
}

fun example2() : String {
 val jsonMapper = JsonMapper()
 val simpleModule = SimpleModule()

 simpleModule.addSerializer(ItemTree::class.java, SerializerB())

 jsonMapper.registerModule(simpleModule)
 return jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(this)
}
```

In my tests, these appear to support different serializers on the same class as desired. But I want to confirm that this is defined behaviour.

Comment: Since you've registered these two serialisers in two different `JsonMapper`s everything is OK. You can use it in this way.

Comment: Thanks! I was worried there may be some kind of dependency via a static field or something magic.

Comment: It is a reasonable question. Fortunately, Jackson, is not implemented in this way and you can create as many as you want `JsonMapper`s and configure them separately. Only annotation on the class level will be reused. But you can overwrite it in the way you showed above.